# Hide/Remove the three little dots (Callout) in a library

Tags: view, library, callouts

I have a library view on one of my pages and i only want to show the title. I adapted the view to only show it. But how to get rid off the three little dots next to a document? I don't want this visible. how can i achieve this please?

Comment: Name (linked to document) is the best, becasue Title comes with *.xml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify the view and select "**Title**" column instead of **Title (linked to item with edit menu)** . If you want Title column to be clickable, which opens the item itself then select **Title (linked to item)** column. For Library use **Name (linked to document)** column if you need to open the document on click of name.